# Can an Xcode project with multiple targets have different Settings.bundle's for each target?

Tags: iphone

I have a settings bundle in an iPhone app which has several subtle variant targets.

The problem is I need to customise some strings in each settings bundle to make them appropriate for each target. It appears that if the Settings bundle is named anything other than Settings.bundle it won't pick up the bundle (understandable, can I specify in a plist somewhere the alternate name?).

If I try and put them in different folders and call them the same thing Xcode gets horribly confused and lets you edit "2 files" that are actually the same single source.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see no problem. For every target, create a specific folder with files for this target. Now create a group in Xcode for every of those folders and drag each of the new Settings.bundle directories to the corresponding group. When adding the bundles to the project, make sure that every bundle is only built (included) for its target by checking the appropriate box.

Comment: This is what I tried but it seems within the file system all the files are contained at the root of project folder so the 2 "seperate" Settings.bundle files are actually a single file. Do I need to manage the filespace manually first before importing them in to Xcode?

Comment: I told you to create a *folder*. For me, that's a filesystem entity. Of course you have to have every bundle on a different, target-specific location.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. As a n00b I'm used to just doing grouping in Xcode and using the 'copy to destination' option a lot. It would actually help my tidy filesystem OCD problem to manage the files nicely in Finder and just drop the references in the project. I got it working now though, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFter you do what MrMage said which is correct.. i had an issue where the Root.plist would not show up under the Settings.Bundle for a specific target.

You have to let xcode know what the setting.bundle file is... click on the settings.bundle that wont show the Root.plist, then go to file inspector

Alter the  file Type drop down to be **applicationBundle**   ... now the Root.plist shows up.