# Multiple targets - multiple Settings.bundle files?

Tags: iphone, xcode, settings.bundle

I am making a iPhone app that has two different targets. They use the same files, with some `#ifdef` here and there, and that works just fine.

But now the project has stopped.
Does anybody know how to have different `Settings.bundles` for both targets?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See answer to [Can an Xcode project with multiple targets have different Settings.bundle's for each target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253606/)  .. short answer yes, you can do it.